# I am converting a object to this array, but cant get the expected array which would consist of Keys as well as values in the array, where am I wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

[image]Trying to convert the below object into array but can not get the expected array.

```
chipsLeaderboardData: "{    
  "100297098919": "380000",
  "100049707310": "21400000",
  "1000990423916": "2000",
  "1001263171666": "17000000",
  "100506562791": "2000",
  "100703099379": "1100000"
}"
```

---My try:---

```
let boardChipsWon = [];
let chipsLeaderboardData = t.chipsLeaderboardData
for (var chip in chipsLeaderboardData) {
   boardChipsWon.push(chipsLeaderboardData[chip])
}
console.log("boardChip won", boardChipsWon)
```

Comment: Is `chipsLeaderboardData` actually an object? It seems like a string to me.. do you run the code after parsing that data using `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: I have added the picture of data I am getting, hope it clarifies the doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `t.chipsLeaderboardData` is actually a json string. You just need to parse it first like:

```
let chipsLeaderboardData = JSON.parse(t.chipsLeaderboardData);
```

and your code should work fine.

```js
let t = { chipsLeaderboardData: '{"100297098919":"380000","100049707310":"21400000","1000990423916":"2000","1001263171666":"17000000","100506562791":"2000","100703099379":"1100000"}' };

let boardChipsWon = [];
let chipsLeaderboardData = JSON.parse(t.chipsLeaderboardData);
for (var chip in chipsLeaderboardData) {
  boardChipsWon.push(chipsLeaderboardData[chip])
}
console.log("boardChip won", boardChipsWon)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

So, basically your code did not work because you were trying to loop over the json string.

Also, instead of `for...in` loop you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method to achieve the same result is one-line like:

```js
let t = { chipsLeaderboardData: '{"100297098919":"380000","100049707310":"21400000","1000990423916":"2000","1001263171666":"17000000","100506562791":"2000","100703099379":"1100000"}'};

let boardChipsWon = Object.values(JSON.parse(t.chipsLeaderboardData));
console.log("boardChip won", boardChipsWon)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

To get key-value pair in the array you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method:

```js
let t = { chipsLeaderboardData: '{"100297098919":"380000","100049707310":"21400000","1000990423916":"2000","1001263171666":"17000000","100506562791":"2000","100703099379":"1100000"}'};

let boardChipsWon = Object.entries(JSON.parse(t.chipsLeaderboardData));
console.log(boardChipsWon)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or a better option like:

```js
let t = { chipsLeaderboardData: '{"100297098919":"380000","100049707310":"21400000","1000990423916":"2000","1001263171666":"17000000","100506562791":"2000","100703099379":"1100000"}'};

let boardChipsWon = Object.entries(JSON.parse(t.chipsLeaderboardData))
  .map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}));
console.log(boardChipsWon)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for advice palaSH, but how do I get a key valye pair in the array, here we see only values correct

Comment: You can use `Object.entries()` method for it. I have also added a demo for it above.

Comment: Yes the "Better option" is all I was aiming for, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the Object.entries() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
          for ( let [key, value] of  Object.entries(chipsLeaderboardData)){
            boardChipsWon.push(value)
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the [JSON](https://json.org/) string and get the values from the object with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
let json = '{"100297098919":"380000","100049707310":"21400000","1000990423916":"2000","1001263171666":"17000000","100506562791":"2000","100703099379":"1100000"}',
    boardChipsWon = Object.values(JSON.parse(json));

console.log("boardChip won", boardChipsWon);
```

Comment: this prints only values, I need keys as well in my application

Comment: please add the wanted result to the question.

Answer (score 0):

as  palaѕн pointed out in the comment, you're likely not using an object but string, here's how you fix it.

```js
let boardChipsWon = [];
let chipsLeaderboardData = JSON.parse(t.chipsLeaderboardData);

for (var chip in chipsLeaderboardData) {
   boardChipsWon.push(chipsLeaderboardData[chip])
}

console.log("boardChip won", boardChipsWon)
```